# Can't locate Session.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, locate

I have a problem with `Session` on Perl.

I am trying to fix this error

```
perl -e "use Session;"
Can't locate Session.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Session module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20 /usr/share/perl/5.20 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1. "
```

I am using Debian 8 64x Server.

I tried:

```
root@division:/usr/lib/cgi-bin# apt-get install libapache-session-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libapache-session-perl is already the newest version.
```

and

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install Session
```

and

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan[1]> install Apache::Session
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
Database was generated on Mon, 29 May 2017 13:41:02 GMT

Apache::Session is up to date (1.93).
```

but still I have the same problem

---

Some information:

```
# echo 'o conf' | perl -MCPAN -e shell | grep -P '^\s+(make|mbuild)'
    make               []
    make_arg           []
    make_install_arg   []
    make_install_make_command []
    makepl_arg         [INSTALLDIRS=site]
    mbuild_arg         []
    mbuild_install_arg []
    mbuild_install_build_command [./Build]
    mbuildpl_arg       [--installdirs site]

# set | grep '^PERL'

# perl -le'print for @INC'
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20.2
/usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20
/usr/share/perl/5.20
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
```

Comment: `libapache-session-perl` [installs the `Apache::Session` module](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/libapache-session-perl/filelist).

Comment: Where did `cpan` install the module?

Comment: root@division:/usr/lib/cgi-bin# apt-get install libapache-session-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libapache-session-perl is already the newest version.

Comment: cpan[1]> install Apache::Session
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 29 May 2017 13:41:02 GMT
Apache::Session is up to date (1.93).

Comment: Which module are you trying to install? Session or Apache::Session???

Comment: i am trying to fix this error "perl -e "use Session;"
Can't locate Session.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Session module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20 /usr/share/perl/5.20 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.
"

Comment: @ikegami trying to resolve my error. but no sucess.

Comment: Then why do you keep installing Apache::Session instead of Session? What output do you get for `perl -MCPAN -e shell` + `install Session`

Comment: perhaps try install CGI::Session http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI-Session-4.48/lib/CGI/Session.pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is:

> Can't locate Session.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Session module)

As the message says, the solution to this problem is to install the [Session](https://metacpan.org/pod/Session) module from CPAN. For some reason, you have tried to solve it by installing the [Apache::Session](https://metacpan.org/pod/Apache::Session) module from CPAN. Session and Apache::Session are two completely different modules. You cannot expect to solve a missing module problem by installing the wrong module.

(Although, I see that Session is a thin wrapper around Apache::Session - so you will need the Apache::Session module installed as well.)

I suggest that you install Session in order to fix your problem.

However, I should point out that the Session module has a single release (version 0.01) which was released in 2003, by someone who hasn't released anything to CPAN since 2005. I'd, therefore, suggest that the chances of getting any support for this module are tiny and I would recommend avoiding the module if at all possible.